# How to use Geocoder to get the current location zip code

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the zip code of the users current location.I have a teditText in MyActivity which should get populated based on the zip code I get from this activity.

```
public class LocationActivity extends MyActivity {
    double LATITUDE;
    double LONGITUDE;

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH); 
    {
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedZip = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder currentZip = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedZip.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strcurrentZip.append(returnedZip.getPostalCode());
                }
                m_zip.setText(strcurrentZip.toString());
            }
            else {
                m_zip.setText("No zip returned!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            m_zip.setText("zip not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting any response,the app logcat does not show any errors but the the editText field I want to populate remains blank.

Comment: You forget to mention what you problem is and what you experience.

Comment: I bet addresses is null, has your GPS or Network provider acquired a location recently?

Comment: One thing I wonder about is, right after you instantiate Geocoder you have a `{` and you end it right after your try/catch, is it really necessary to scope it that way? Or is it a mistake that you put `;` right after new Geocoder() so it is a part of the instantiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ...

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type=\"postal_code\"]/long_name/text()";
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng="+VARIABLECONTAININGLATITUDE+","+VARIABLECONTAININGLONGITUDE+"&sensor=true");
String zipcode = (String) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

where VARIABLECONTAININGLATITUDE and VARIABLECONTAININGLONGITUDE are latitudes and longitudes from GPS or whatever location provider you choose.

also you need permission internet in manifest and location permission in manifest

Answer (score 1):

Please write below code for get zip code

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentlat, currentlng, 1);
```

Now the list of Address contains the closest known areas. The Address object has the getPostalCode() function. Grab the first object and find it's Postal code.